# What is the latest iOS version for iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-id

I want to download the latest iOS version for offline restore for my iPhone 4. I want to know what is the latest iOS version and how can I download it?

Answer (score 6):

The latest iOS available for the iPhone 4 is iOS 7.1.2

Have a look at: [Maximum Supported iOS Version](https://everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html)

The direct download links for the full releases are:

[iPhone 4 (GSM Rev A)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7.1/031-4785.20140627.zZ42j/iPhone3,2_7.1.2_11D257_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 4 (GSM)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7.1/031-4812.20140627.cq6y8/iPhone3,1_7.1.2_11D257_Restore.ipsw)

[iPhone 4 (CDMA)](http://appldnld.apple.com/iOS7.1/031-4768.20140627.DXmmp/iPhone3,3_7.1.2_11D257_Restore.ipsw)

Download the appropriate file for your device and then in iTunes select the device and option-click the Check for Update button and select the downloaded .ipsw file.

Also, if you Google "how to install ios from file using itunes" (without quotes) you'll find additional information.

Comment: Please note that at the time this answer was posted it was valid, however, it's now over two years later and even though the file can still be downloaded, I do not know if it can still be used to restore from as its certificate might now be expired. If anyone has tested a recent restore and it worked, it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone 4 is the most recent iPhone to be discontinued from the iOS Update cycle. It did not receive the iOS 8 update, so it's final software version is `iOS 7.1.2`. You can update to this version through iTunes, or download it from an IPSW repository like this website: https://ipsw.me/

Comment: I tested the links this site generates and they eventually resolve to the Apple download servers. That said, in general, it is best to avoid downloading software when you cannot easily tell where it is originating.

Comment: The current version is 7.1.2 ... It may be the final version.  But there could still be a 7.1.3 in the future if there is some security hole or something that Apple decides to fix.