# Please help me with iPhone updating problems I've been having

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

My iPhone 4 is at iOS 7. I try to update it but it says the phone is up to date. How do I change that? I want the newest iOS version.

Comment: [See this Answer.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174061/what-is-the-latest-ios-version-for-iphone-4)  iOS 7 is the highest version the hardware of iPhone 4 supports.

Comment: The iPhone 4 is not a supported device of the latest iOS, currently 9.0.2.  The iPhone 4 supports up to iOS 7.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 4 is incompatible with version of iOS above iOS 7.1.2.

The reason you are not seeing updates available is because future iOS versions are incompatible.